# Save xml file text in databse using node.js

Tags: mysql, xml, node.js

I am trying to save xml string to MySQL database here is my code:-
I am using MySQL module for manage database;

```
   //I am reading the xml file from path using this code
   var stream = fs.createReadStream(path);
   stream.setEncoding('utf8');
   stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
     var text=chunk.toString('utf8');
     //here is the error i.e invalid syntax in MySQL query
     con.query('insert into table_name(text) values("'+text+'")',function(err,data){
         //allways getting error.
     });         
   });
```

I know the error because of invalid characters in text variable. So how I can concatenate or escape the string please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your query from parameters like this:

```
 con.query('insert into table_name(text) values(?)', [text], function(err,data){
    //...
  })
```

this way text is escaped automatically by mysql client library